# Typo3 7: memory limit exceeded in backend

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have 2 database tables:

```
tx_pg_domain_model_item
fe_groups
```

It is possible to assign various groups to an item, so in my TCA for tx_pg_domain_model_item it looks something like this:

```
    'groups' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'groups',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'fe_groups',
            'MM' => 'tx_pg_item_groups_group_mm',
            'size' => 5,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
        ),
    ),
```

The problem is, there are a lot of groups and so as the database grew bigger and bigger recently trying to edit an item in the backend no longer worked. I looked at the errorlog and it says this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
```

now my question is: is there another way to do this to make this work? Some kind of lazy loading maybe or can you guys think of any other alternative?

Comment: does this error occur for every editor? you might get memory exhaustion if there are too many states stored in your session data for the state of trees to display. try clearing all user data: there is a  "Reset Configuration and Clear Temporary Data" in the 'user settings' in the tab 'Edit and Advanced functions'.

Comment: thank you, I tried that but didn't change the error. And it happens to multiple users, not just one, unfortunately

Comment: aside of giving more memory: if changing the rendertype gives no better results you might need to write a wizard which handle the big amount of data in smaller chunks or use immediate database access on very few fields instead of extbase's full records

Comment: can you please show the whole code. I think thats not the only part which is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use `group` instead of `select`.

`select` loads all fe_users while loading your form in the backend. If you have too much users, there will be this memory fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase your php memory_limit into your php.ini file.
for eg.

```
; Old Limit
; memory_limit = 512M

; New Limit
memory_limit = 1048M
```

then again restart your apache server.

Comment: be careful with increasing the limit! You will need more available rum then. Better refactor the code and make clean code